# How to set up a server that others on my work network can access using node.js?

Tags: node.js, server, httpserver

I'm very new to node.js, I've created a server two ways.

One way like this:

server.js:

```
var connect = require("connect");
var serveStatic = require("serve-static");
connect().use(serveStatic(__dirname)).listen(8080);
```

node.js cmd line:

```
H:\> npm install connect serve-static
H:\> node server.js
```

And the other way like this

```
H:\> npm install http-server -g
http-server "C:\directory"
```

But these just create servers on my computer at `http://localhost:8080`. How can I adjust this code to make the server accessible for other people on my work network?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is accessible from your network already.  Just use your IP address or real hostname.

```
http://203.0.113.1:8080/
```